# Laravel - Emails not including data when sent via Queue

Tags: laravel-5.3

I'm trying to set up a Contact Form and all is going well. Set up my Controller with ->send(), all works fine (takes a bit of time). When I set it up to work with ->queue(), seems to work fine (no delay), job is set up, mail is sent when I dispatch. But this time my mail template does not include the data sent to the Mailer.

My Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Mail\Contact;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class PagesController extends Controller
{

  public function sendContact(Request $request)
    {

        Mail::to('webform@email.com')

            ->queue(new Contact($request));

        return redirect('/contact')->with('status', 'Message sent. Thanks!');
    }
}
```

My Mailer (App\Mail\Contact):

```
class Contact extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;


    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {


    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build(Request $request)
    {
        $subject = 'Web Message from: ' . $request->name;

        return $this->from('myemail@email.com')
            ->subject($subject)
            ->view('emails.contact-template')
            ->with([
                'name'     =>$request->name,
                'email'    => $request->email,
                'message'  => $request->message,
                'date'     => $request->date,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I needed to declare the variables as public. Below is the solution that eventually worked:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class Contact extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $request;
    public $name;
    public $from;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request->all();
        $this->name = $request->name;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {

        $subject =  'Webform messsage from: ' . $this->name;
        $from = 'webform@mail.com';

        return $this
            ->from( $from )
            ->subject($subject)
            ->view('emails.contact-template');

    }
}
```